# Excel: new rules for conditional formatting if I filter my table

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

This is rather annoying. I created some rules for conditional formatting, that are applied to my table.
If I filter my table for example to only show some values, some rows are hidden and the values I was looking for are displayed. But if I check the rules in conditional formatting, I can see that Excel creates double rules over the existing ones every time I filter my tables. The new rules are equal to the previous ones but the area in which they are applied is different (I think it corresponds to the area of the filtered items).

The annoying thing is that these rules are permanent and are mantained also if I reset my table filters.

Is there a way to "lock" conditional formatting rules and prevent the automatic addition of these rules?

Comment: Excel 2013. Tables as "Format as table". I don't have the formula right now but it was like "color the row of blue if in column L text is equal to blabla".

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-known problem from Excel 2007 onwards. The only really effective solution is to use something like VBA to reapply the Conditional Formatting after filtering/unfiltering. However, depending somewhat on the rule, there are various workarounds for particular circumstances, many detailed by [Debra Dalgleish](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/06/21/excel-2010-conditional-formatting-nightmare/) or in comments to her blog. I didn't notice there so add that applying a rule to a complete column may also avoid the problem, in some cases.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. It's the same problem. But they resolve by adding empty cells at the end of the table. No fix for filtering :(